# General methods of solving non-linear recurrences

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Let's consider a sequence $$ \{a_{n} \} _{n=0}^{\infty}, a_{0}=1, a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}}{1+na_{n}}$$.

Taking $$b_{n}=\frac{1}{a_{n}},$$ we bring the exact recurrence to the following one: $$b_{0}=1, b_{n+1}=b_{n}+n,$$ which is a linear one and can be handled with general methods.

This particular example presumes taking a particular substitution, while it seems to be quite challenging to cope with the problem without using it (guessing the potential exact form of $a_{n}$ and then proving it by the induction seems possible but it does fail in more sophisticated sequences). Are there any general methods to approach non-linear recurrence sequences ?

For example, the $\{a_{n} \}$ generation function evaluation seems quite intricate, probably, not even possible to do it by hand (?). Also, the situation goes worse, if we put some transcendental functions into recurrence, for example, considering $$x_{0}=1,x_{n+1}=\frac{\log{\sin{x_{n}}}}{\tan{x_{n-1}}}$$ 
Apparently, the previous example does not allow us to establish an explicit form of $x_{n}$ because it probably does not exist, so it might be interesting to get the ways how to prove it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is just a heuristic rule I use. If the differential equation version of the recurrence relation can't be solved in closed form, then the recurrence probably has no closed form.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use differential equations to solve this. We have $f(x+1)=\frac{f(x)}{1+xf(x)}$. The recurrence equations solution is, $$f(x)=\frac{1}{c_{1}+x}$$. Now we must find out what $c_{1}$ could be.

$f(0)=1=\frac{1}{c_{1}}$ therefore $c_{1}=1$ therefore $a_n=\frac{1}{1+n}$.

Comment: You could also try induction I suppose.

Comment: @Alexsandar
Well, yes, in this particular case it's possible, but not always.
Regarding your answer - you've established the solution of the functional equation. As for me, the most natural way to do it without using 'a bag of tricks' is to consider the solutions in the form of a power series $f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+\ldots$, but it actually will lead the     instant non-linear reccurence relation.

Comment: I know. In such case maybe a method like hypothesizing a sequence then proving it by induction (if it is the case).